# How to limit prometheus data aggreagation with specific time range?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a metric with TPS in a business scenario. I want to get a percentile for a certain period of time.
If I use a zabbix data source, I get this(which I really need):

[grafana+zabbix+percentile.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfDhV.png)

If I use the prometheus data source, I get this:

[grafana+prometheus+percentile.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djro0.png)

```
query: quantile_over_time(0.75, sum(metric_group{ metric="metric_name"})[3d:])
```

I want to get several points on the chart with an interval of 3 days, as it was done in the first chart. But in the case of using Prometheus, I get many points with an interval of 5 minutes, instead of 3 days.
How to fix this and limit this data?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `min step` value to `3d` in graph settings in Grafana. See more details about `min step` setting in Grafana at https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/ .